# Combobox show value member

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datepicker

```
private class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public string Value;
    public Item(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name; Value = value;
    }

    cmb_1.Items.Add(new Item("mykonos", "1"));
    cmb_1.Items.Add(new Item("Paros", "2"));
    cmb_1.Items.Add(new Item("Nobugz", "666"));
```

I have this code. When I choose "mykonos" for example from `ComboBox` I would like to show dialog number 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

cmb_1.SelectedItem is Item object.

```
        Item selectedItem = cmb_1.SelectedItem as Item;
        if (selectedItem != null)
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("selected Item value:{0}, name:{1}", selectedItem.Value, selecteItem.Name));
        else
            MessageBox.Show("no selected item");
```

Comment: i edited again because i think that your answer is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

Create your class like and override `ToString()` method to return the value you want.

```
    class Item
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
```

Add items to your `ComboBox`:

```
        cmb_1.Items.Add(new Item() { Text= "mykonos", Value="1" });
        cmb_1.Items.Add(new Item() { Text = "Paros", Value = "2" });
        cmb_1.Items.Add(new Item() { Text = "Nobugz", Value = "666" });
        cmb_1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

And within `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler, do this:

```
    private void cmb_1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(cmb_1.SelectedItem!=null)
            MessageBox.Show((cmb_1.SelectedItem as Item).Value.ToString());
    }
```

`ShowDialog` doesn't work like you want, it does work with the `Forms`. You can simply use `MessageBox.Show` to verify. This is tested code.

Hope it helps.